# android html post

Tags: android, html, http

I am new to android. I created an http server working to localhost till now. In this server, I have the following html form:

```
static final String HTML_FORM=
        "<form action=\"http://localhost:5000/doSearch\" enctype=\"multipart/form-data\""+
        " method=\"post\"> "+
        "track <input name=\"track\" type=\"text\"  ><br>" +
        "artist<input name=\"artist\" type=\"text\"><br>"+
        "<input value=\"Search\" type=\"submit\"></form>";
```

Whenever I access the localhost first from the android emulator ( 10.0.2.2:5000) I am directed to the page containing the form. Then when I submit the form, I am not redirected to localhost:5000/doSearch page. I tried changing the localhost in the form to 10.0.2.2 but it simply won't work. Hope you can help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Strugglin with this issue

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=133

Comment: i can see that is is a common issue, however no solution was specified in that link. any recommendations of what is the best way to work around it?

Comment: nop Im still tryin to solve this, but i leave that proyect 3 months ago =(